# Placing $n$ rooks peacefully on a board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, chessboard

We got $n\times n$ board colored in different colors. The count of cells with the same color is $\leq \frac{n-1}{16}$. Prove that we can manage to place $n$ rooks on different color cells, so they were "peacefully"(without attacking each other) on board.

Can someone give a hint how to solve this problem?
I think we should represent this board as graph, and make graph-coloring task out of this one, but I couldn't manage to do it on my own.

Comment: What's ''Peacefully'' placed ?

Comment: @Hamdiken possibly, without attacking each other? so each rook is on a distinct row and column

Comment: @CalvinKhor Surely you realize that the less information that is given as to what the OP (i.e. original poster) intends, the greater the artistic challenge will be in telepathically determining and then solving the problem.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree that that is true, but I am unable to draw an 'ought' from the 'is'? I am willing to assume that OP simply could not find the words. I think its the only reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the meaning of your board "colored of different colors". However, you may be interested by the following site : https://oeis.org/A000903. There are number of references concerning your problem (or similar problem). Don't look at it if you don't want to be spoiled ! :-)

Comment: This about traversals of Latin squares, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: @ZachHunter, in latin squares each symbol occurs ones(in rows and columns), which isn't the case here I guess

Comment: Yeah I was a bit sloppy with wording, I had in mind a relaxation of Latin squares.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes that's the way MSE works. I regularly have to ask for clarification of terminology, to be told "If you need to know what xyz means, you're not clever enough to be able to answer the question. It is against MSE policy to explain what you mean."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question can be found as Theorem 5.6.1 of Alon and Spencer’s book on the probabilistic method.

The theorem states: let $A$ be an $n\times n$-matrix, where no value appears in more than $(n-1)/4e$ entires. Then $A$ contains a “traversal” (or in other words, there exists a permutation $\pi$ such that $A_{1,\pi(1)},\dots,A_{n,\pi(n)}$ are all distinct values).

Please correct me if this not what you’re asking about.

The proof in the book uses a variant of the Lovasz Local Lemma. It’s a bit long, so I won’t copy it here (though if I have time later I might add something). Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right, but this theorem isn't in my book, on the other hand Lovasz Local Lemma is. Proving the theorem is pretty hard. Task is denoted as medium.

Comment: Applying the local lemma directly produces a rather annoying proof. There is a variant of the local lemma for random permutations and more generally random injections (see [the paper](https://doi.org/10.37236/981) by Lu and Székely) and if we apply Theorem 1 from that paper then checking the conditions of the local lemma is straightforward.